# Inverse search from Zathura to .tex file

Tags: terminal

With the help of someone on this stack I was able to configure vim so that it launches with a server name that is the filename it opens. For example, if I run `vim filename.tex`, vim will launch with the server name "filename". My issue now is using Zathura as a previewer when I compile and preview my .tex file, I want to be able to inverse search. This requires me to be able to configure Zathura so that the instance of Zathura that is previewing filename.pdf will inverse search to the vim window with the "filename" server.

Currently in my `zathurarc` I have the following,

`set synctex-editor-command "vim --servername +%{1} --remote-silent +%{line} %{input}"`

This does not work though. So I am hoping someone here will have a suggestion to get me on the right track? Is this even possible?

EDIT: The terminal with vim open just returns this error:
[image]

Comment: Please don't describe a problem with "it doesn't work". How exactly does it not work? Error message? Does it work when run directly (`vim --servername ...`)? The more details the better.

Comment: You might be interested in trying out [VimTeX](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex/), which has good support for Zathura as a viewer, including backward search.

Comment: See also: [pdftex - How to setup synctex with vim, pdflatex and an open-source PDF-viewer under Linux? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2941/how-to-setup-synctex-with-vim-pdflatex-and-an-open-source-pdf-viewer-under-linu/412366#412366)